# How can I improve my question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[Question here.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/321285/sp-blitzcache-detecting-thousands-of-executions-of-create-procedure-dbo-commande)

I did my best to follow Stack guidelines:

1. The question is formatted nicely with code and tables in appropriate forms. Where possible, I pared these down to just the relevant information. With substitutions for file paths and database names, the code is functional.
2. I tried solving the problem myself by googling the symptoms and couldn't find anything.
3. The title is a summary of the problem, not some vague 'I need help with x'.

Despite this, my question got downvoted twice with no explanation.